# Error calling a base class method from a derived class object. Both base and derived classes are templated

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I'm practicing some C++ inheritance concepts with templates. I wrote this base class:

```
template <typename type1, typename type2>
class baseClass {
private:
    type1 member1;
    type2 member2;

public:
    baseClass() {};
    baseClass(type1 member1, type2 member2):member1(member1), member2(member2) {};
    type1 get_member1();
    type2 get_member2();
    ~baseClass() {};
};
```

and a derived class:

```
template <typename type1, typename type2, typename type3>
class derivedClass : public baseClass<type1, type2> {
private:
    type3 member3;
public:
    derivedClass(){};
    derivedClass(type1 member1, type2 member2, type3 member3): baseClass<type1, type2>(member1, member2), member3(member3){};
    type3 get_member3();
};
```

And I'm doing this manipulation from the main function:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    derivedClass<int, int, int> object(1, 2, 3);
    cout << object.get_member1() << endl;
    cout << object.get_member1() << " " << object.get_member2() << " " << object.get_member3() << endl;
}
```

The compiler gives error when I try to compile the above program. I tried searching for this problem online but didn't get any specific answer. I'm new to C++ templates and don't know how to deal with them yet. Please help me figure it out. Thanks!

Edit: The definition of the get_member* methods:

```
template <typename type1, typename type2>
type1 baseClass<type1, type2>::get_member1() {
    return member1;
}

template <typename type1, typename type2>
type2 baseClass<type1, type2>::get_member2() {
    return member2;
}

template <typename type1, typename type2, typename type3>
type3 derivedClass<type1, type2, type3>::get_member3() {
    return member3;
}
```

Comment: What error(s) ? Linker ?

Comment: Definition of `get_member1()` and `get_member2()` is missing

Comment: Well, yes, if that code you show here is all you have, then you are missing the definition of the get_... methods.

Comment: Those functions are defined in another cpp file.

Comment: This is the error I'm getting: 
`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "derivedClass<int, int, int>::get_member3()", referenced from:
      _main in mainFile.o
  "baseClass<int, int>::get_member1()", referenced from:
      _main in mainFile.o
  "baseClass<int, int>::get_member2()", referenced from:
      _main in mainFile.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: If the functions are defined in a source file, did you make sure to supply the compiler with that source file, and/or the linker with an object file compiled from that source file?  For example, if the functions are defined in `memberFuncs.cpp`, did you use `clang++ mainFile.cpp` or `clang++ mainFile.cpp memberFuncs.cpp`?

Answer (score 0):

See here : [corrected-code](http://ideone.com/Tq0P0O)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename type1, typename type2>
class baseClass {
private:
    type1 member1;
    type2 member2;

public:
    baseClass() {}
    baseClass(type1 member1, type2 member2):member1(member1), member2(member2) {}
    type1 get_member1(){return member1;}
    type2 get_member2(){return member2;}
    virtual ~baseClass() {};
};

template <typename type1, typename type2, typename type3>
class derivedClass : public baseClass<type1, type2> {
private:
    type3 member3;
public:
    derivedClass(){};
    derivedClass(type1 member1, type2 member2, type3 member3):     baseClass<type1, type2>(member1, member2), member3(member3){};
    type3 get_member3() {return member3;}
    ~derivedClass(){}
};


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    derivedClass<int, int, int> object(1, 2, 3);
    cout << object.get_member1() << endl;
    cout << object.get_member1() << " " << object.get_member2() << " " <<    object.get_member3() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hey, having the definition of the get_member function within the class solves the problem, but can you please help me understand what is wrong in my declaration of the functions in a separate cpp file. I've added the code in the updated question. Thanks!

Comment: You may want to provide the declaration of baseClass and derivedClass in  a header file and use another .cpp file to add the definitions of the functions. Don't forget to include the header file in the .cpp file.

Comment: Yeah, that's how it is right now. Doesn't work. Is there some problem with the way I have defined the functions in the cpp file?

Comment: @Monster, please suggest as to why the answer was unaccepted ?